# If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct solutions of the differential equation $\ddot{x}+a_1(t)\dot{x}+a_2(t)=0$, show the solutions are linearly dependent.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

We are given that $a_1$ and $a_2$ are continuous functions that have a maximum or a minimum at the same $t$, for some $t\in I$. I tried using Abel's Identity with the Wronskian, showing that $$W'(x_1,x_2)=a_2(t)(x_1-x_2)+W(x_1,x_2)$$ Since it is a non-homogeneous equation, I tried to solve first the homogeneous equation $$W'(x_1,x_2)-W(x_1,x_2)=0$$ Then I got $$W(x_1,x_2)=e^{t-t^*+\ln\left({W(x_1(t^*),x_2(t^*)}\right)}$$ That was integrating both sides from $t^*$ to $t$. However, I got stuck here, because I need to show $W(x_1,x_2)=0$, so $x_1,x_2$ are linearly dependent solutions. Plus, I tried to solve the original differential equation, but it's too messy to find the Wronskian of the particular and general solution of this differential equation.

Comment: The statement is not quite true as given, because it doesn't preclude the possibility that $\ x_2=x_1\ $.You need to specify at least that $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $ are *distinct* solutions.

Comment: Thanks, let me fix that, since $x_1$ and $x_2$ are distinct solutions.

Comment: Are you sure that the equation you typed is correct? Did not you miss $x(t)$?

Comment: No, the problem is written like that, and I can see why you mention it because I saw other questions similar but with $x(t)$ multiplied by $a_2(t)$.

Comment: I completely misread your question. But it still seems that you miss $x$ in your equation.

Comment: If you have a non-homogeneous equation its solutions are not elements of some vector space, and hence asking whether they are linearly dependent is meaningless.

Comment: You are right, then let me check for that $x(t)$. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I misread the question earlier as being to show that  $\ x_1\ $ and  $\ x_2\ $ are linearly *independent*. My previous comment is therefore incorrect. If  $\ x_1=x_2\ $ then they're automatically linearly dependent, so it's not necessary to require them to be distinct (though it doesn't really matter if you do).

Comment: $a_1=a_2=0$ and $x_1=t$, $x_2=t+1$ should be a counter example.

Comment: In fact, if $\ a_2\ne0\ $, then *no* pair of distinct solutions can be linearly dependent. If $\ x_1\ $ and $\ x_2\ $ are solutions satisfying $\ ax_1+bx_2=0\ $ with $\ a,b\ne0\ $ then $ 0=(a+b)\ddot{x}+$$a_1(t)(a+b)\dot{x}=$$-(a+b)a_2(t)\ $, which implies $\ a=-b\ $ and hence $\ x_1=x_2\ $.

Comment: The first sentence should be that $a_1,a_2$ are continuous, and that $x_1,x_2$ are twice continuously differentiable with a common maximum. Then the question makes sense in the version of the linear DE, with $...+a_2x=0$.

Comment: The statement of the title is false: for $x_1,x_2$ a basis of solutions (i.e. such that $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2\cr \dot{x_1} & \dot{x_2}\end{pmatrix}$ is a fundamental matrix of the ED in the vector form), we do not have linear dependance.